# Using functions from within the same class

Tags: php, class, function

This is probably a really simple question however Google isn't my friend today.

I have something like this but it says call to undefined function

```php
<?php
    class myClass{
        function doSomething($str){
            //Something is done here
        }
        function doAnother($str){
            return doSomething($str);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try the following:

```
return $this->doSomething($str);
```

Comment: You can also use self::doSomething($str); as well

Answer (score 26):

You can try a static call like this:

```
function doAnother ($str) {
    return self::doSomething($str);
}
```

Or if you want to make it a dynamic call, you can use $this keyword, thus calling a function 
of a class instance:

```
function doAnother ($str) {
    return $this->doSomething($str);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
return $this->doSomething($str);
```

Have a look at this as well: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
return $this->doSomething(str);
```